# How to make a computer not detect flash drive?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, access-control

One of my acquaintances often comes to me with his pen drive and uses my laptop for a long time, which gets me annoyed.

How do I make my machine temporarily *not* detect any external flash drive ?

Comment: How exactly is disabling external drives going to prevent him from using your laptop?

Comment: oh grow some and tell him you need your laptop and he should find an internet cafe or somebody else or get his own.. that's more respectable than pretending your usb detection isn't working.

Comment: Some BIOSes let you disable some of the USB ports.

Comment: This can be handled by a group policy.  You can modify the permissions of the User account the user will use, the user won't be able to use the flash storage device, but you really should just kick them of if you that annoyed by somebody.

Comment: @barlop but he won.t grow and will come back to me ... btw, i wanted a technical solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regedit` and modify value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor` to **4**. When you want USB drives to work again, change it back to whatever it was before (probably **3**).

There are also [tools](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2007/01/disable-usb-flash-drives/) that do it for you automatically.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/823732/en

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel, Device Manager and disable the USB drivers.

Comment: Won't this disable the external mouse and keyboard, too?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I can understand an external mouse, but you need a second keyboard too? Oh, yes, it will if they use a USB port.

Comment: Which USB drivers? All? Then other USB devices won't work. @Zaroth's solution is much better, and more descriptive than a general "disable the drivers".

Comment: @Colin'tHart I never said it was the best plan. I agree Zaroth's solution is better.